# Stop receiving text messages in my Samsung Note 8 that are sent from spammers email address

Tags: samsung, sms, email, spam

I have been getting unwanted text messages on my Samsung Note 8 coming from a spammers email account.

I have not found a way to block these text messages coming from email accounts.  The feature that I use to block phone numbers is not available.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You receive only spam from one account - you are lucky. Typically is an mail account gets older you receive spam from hundred of spammers once your mail address has been recognized by a spammer.

Spam protection typically a job of your mail provider. Often the "SPAM detection report" is hidden in the mail header. On most mail providers you can use the fields in the mail header to move mails to certain sub-folders, e.g. in this case to a "potential spam" folder in your mailbox. Mail provider can reject spam messages so that they never reach you. I would assume that this already happens if you only receive SPAM from one sender.

Additionally you can check if your mail provider allows you to provide new SPAM samples so that they might get recognized in the future. Sometimes there is an e-mail address you can forward SPAM messages (as attachment) to or you can mark message as SPAM in the mail provider web GUI.

Very few mail clients include a client side SPAM protection based on machine learning. Bt typically such systems are more common on desktop PCs (e.g. in Thunderbird). In Android apps such a self-learning SPAM protection is not that common (I don't know any app that would provide such a feature).